# Get CMake's Ninja test command

Tags: cmake, ninja

I'm trying to make Ninja work with CMake on [FreeBSD 10.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD#Version_history):

```
cmake -GNinja ..
-- Configuring done
CMake Error:
  The detected version of Ninja () is less than the version of Ninja required
  by CMake (1.3).

-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/pj/_build
```

I have put a locally compiled (from Git tag v1.8.2) Ninja in `~/bin/ninja` (which is in my `$PATH`).

```
$ cmake -version
cmake version 3.4.1
$ ninja --version
1.8.2
```

I also tried to add `-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=ninja` and `-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=~/bin/ninja` without effect.

I also tried to see if Ninja was really called (by putting a script writing a new file), and it looks like it's never called.

Is there a way to see which commands are used to to check the Ninja version?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I got similar issue and the answers below seems not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By inspecting the generated CMakeCache.txt file, you should be able to tell which Ninja version is picked by CMake.

In `CMakeCache.txt` you should have something similar to:

```
// Path to a program.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ninja
```

which could tell which Ninja version is picked by default and whether `-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` is respected or from some reason ignored.

Also, it is worth looking into the generated `CMakeOutput.log` and `CMakeError.log` files.

I would also suggest adding `ninja` to your PATH, hoping CMake would pick it from there.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get this error message when forgetting to call `project(my_project)` before calling `add_library` or `add_executable`.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question while getting the same error message.  What I forgot to do was delete the CMakeCache.txt file before I ran `cmake` with the `-GNinja` or `-DCMAKE_GENERATOR=Ninja` options.  So `cmake` was pulling the cached variable.